# Listview and a button in the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, button, android-relativelayout

I've tried everything, and looked up everywhere..!

I'm trying to put a listview within a scrollview, and a button at the bottom of the screen fixed..
This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlCommento" /> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlCommento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etCCommento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCInviaCommento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etCCommento"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="85"
            android:text="Commenta!" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems working in the project, but when I try it on the emulator, it doesn't work!
Any advice ? Thanks!

Comment: ListView within scrollview bad idea

Comment: where is scrollview?? i don't see a scrollview at all

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have to do:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlCommento"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Don't put list view inside scroll view
Second: make your top most parent width n height to match parent
Third: add a new layout at bottom and add button inside this layout, something like this, give layout some weight

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/score_board"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="OK" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlCommento"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etCCommento"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCInviaCommento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Commenta!" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you have to LinearLayout vertical instead of RelativeLayout and set ListView weight=1 and layout_height=0dp.
This should work just as needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" /> 

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlCommento"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCCommento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bCInviaCommento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etCCommento"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="85"
        android:text="Commenta!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your problem correctly. No need of keeping ListView inside scrollview. Just try following snippet. It will may for you.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         /> 

<Button
            android:id="@+id/bCInviaCommento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Commenta!"
            android:layout_below="@id/list" />

</RelativeLayout?
```